# RoundRect does not fit in JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I have a JFrame with a class that extends JPanel added to it with BorderLayout.CENTER. In the JPanel subclass in the paintComponent method I am drawing a fillRoundRect with the same dimensions as the JFrame. When I run it the bottom and right part of the roundRect are cut off.

In the main class I have this:

```java
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    PlayingField playingField = new PlayingField(); // subclass of JPanel
    frame.add(playingField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
});
```

And in PlayingField I have:

```java
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, 500, 500, 50, 50);
}
```

I want the roundRect to fit perfectly in the JFrame with the edges of the roundRect touching the edges of the JFrame.

Comment: Note for future questions.. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am drawing a fillRoundRect with the same dimensions as the JFrame.

You should NOT be using the same dimensions as the frame. The frame includes decorations (title bar and borders).

Also, you should NOT be hardcoding values. How will your painting work if the frame is resized?

Instead you should be using the actual size of the panel:

```
g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), 50, 50);
```

Now the painting is dynamic based on the size of the panel.